# ConstraintViolationException: Could not insert object

Tags: java, orm

I am implementing a banking application and have three tables in my database (User, Account and AccountActivity):

[image: database schema fragment]

The implementation of the `Account` and `AccountActivity` classes look like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass public abstract class AbstractDomain implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id = NEW_ID;

    public static long NEW_ID = -1;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id; 
    }

    public boolean isNew() {

        return id==NEW_ID;
    }
}

@Table(name="ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY") 
@Entity
public class AccountActivity extends AbstractDomain {
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="XDATE")
    private Date Date;

    @Column(name="VALUE")
    private double Value;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNTID")
    private Account ACCOUNT;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="OTHERACCOUNTID")
    private Account OTHERACCOUNT;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And:

```
@Table(name="ACCOUNT") 
@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractDomain {
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="XDATE")
    private Date Date;

    @Column(name="VALUE")
    private double Value;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USERID")
    private User USER;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AccountActivity> AccountActivity = new ArrayList<AccountActivity>();

    // ...
}
```

To store new accounts in my database I use this:

```
public Account storeAccount(Account ac) {
    User x = ac.getUser();
    x = em.merge(x);
    ac = em.merge(ac);
    return ac;
}
```

which works to just store new accounts in my database. I wanted to implement the functionality that when account activity information is added to an already saved account,
that account will be updated and the added information (account activity) is cascaded to the
AccountActivity table using this piece of code:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<AccountActivity> AccountActivity = new ArrayList<AccountActivity>();
```

When I test this code I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Integrity constraint violation -no parent
>   FK670B7D019607336A table: ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY in statement

Can anybody help me with this problem?

*update*

I test with this piece of junit code:

```
public void testAddAccountActivities() {

    User user = dummyPersistedUser();
    User user2 = dummyPersistedUser();

    Account account = getTestUtils().dummyEmptyAccount(user);
    Account account2 = getTestUtils().dummyEmptyAccount(user2);

    account=accountManager.storeAccount(account);
    account2=accountManager.storeAccount(account2);

    getTestUtils().fillAccounts(account, account2);

    accountManager.storeAccount(account);
    accountManager.storeAccount(account2);

    assertEquals(2,accountManager.getAccount4Name(account.getName()).getAccountActivity().size());
    assertEquals(2,accountManager.getAccount4Name(account2.getName()).getAccountActivity().size());

}
```

where `fillAccounts(account, account2)` just inserts some AccountActivities that should be added to the graph.:

```
AccountActivity aa = new AccountActivity();
    aa.setDate(new Date());
    aa.setName("test activity");
    aa.setAccount(a1);
    aa.setValue(value);
    aa.setOtherAccount(a2);
    account.addAccountActivity(aa)
```

Comment: Where are the @Id definitions for your entity classes?

Comment: I forgot to mention that those @ID definitions are inherited from the AbstractDomain class (see updated version of question)

Comment: Show us the code of your test. How do you test the application?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the configuration of AccountActivity in Account.java. The error is thrown when I try to merge ac in storeAccount, which result in a merce of account and should result in an update of that AccountActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name ="accountid") // you have several references from AccountActivity to Account. You need to specify the join column in this case.
private List<AccountActivity> AccountActivity = new ArrayList<AccountActivity>();
```

Answer (score -1):

As a first observation, I think you shouldn't have the variable name the same as the class. So, instead of this private List <AccountActivity> AccountActivity, you can write something like private List <AccountActivity> accountActivity.